# Change layout at runtime NULL POINTER EXCEPTION

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, view, android-view

I am opening one dialog box in that there is two option button when i select any of one the layout should be change below is screen shot

[image]

now there is list.xml files which is below and in that there is two linear layout

english (which is english-telugu list) english word display first then telugu word

```
      <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/engRowOfList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEng"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <com....TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGuj"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        lht:ttf_name="fonts/telugu.ttf" />
</LinearLayout>
```

telugu ( in that telugu word is displaying first and then english word is displaying

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/teluguRowOfList"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com......GujTextView
        android:id="@+id/txtEng"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        lht:ttf_name="fonts/telugu.ttf" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtGuj"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/orange"
        android:textSize="22dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

As of many suggest that you can do by LinearLayout.GONE/LinearLayout.VISIBLE so i have tried in below code but still can not do it below is my code

```
   scAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            R.layout.list, cursor, new String[] { Const.ENGLISH,
                    Const.TELUGU }, new int[] { R.id.txtEng,
                    R.id.txtTelugu });

    scAdapter.setViewBinder(new ViewBinder() {

        public boolean setViewValue(View view,
                android.database.Cursor cursor, int columnIndex) {

            engListView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.engList);
            teluguListView = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.teluguList);

            if (flagEnFl) { //flag for ENGLISH / TELUGU 
                engListView.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);  ***//HERE I AM GETTING NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION EVERY TIME***
                teluguListView.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                engListView.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                teluguListView.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE);
            }
```

could any body help me how to handle this situation

Comment: why don't you create only one layout and change content of textviews when user select any option..

Comment: But Armaan when i change content of textview (English text is not displaying properly for example when i choose "@+id/txtGuj" and in that when i place english text, then eng text will not display properly :(*

Comment: may be its because you have used ttf fonts for telugu. so i think you have to change fonts at the runtime according to option selection.

Comment: when there is english tamil then set font to tamil.ttf and when there is tamil english then set font to any english font like verdana.ttf. so that will make it work.

Comment: Thank you so much Armaan for giving me nice suggestion :) but can u know me how can i set property lht:ttf_name="fonts/telugu.ttf"  at run time??

Answer (score 0):

Merge two layout files into one. Hide views that shouldn't be shown firstly.
When user selects from dialog, hide dialog and show desired view.

Comment: Thank you so much for your nice reply this way also i can do thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution

Combine both layout in one as following then make them `VISIBLE` and `GONE`

```
<LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/englishLayour>

    </LinearLayout>
   <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/englishLayour>

   </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            if(checkedId==R.id.radioEnglish);
            {
                  englishLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                  tamilLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            }else{
                  englishLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                  tamilLayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);              
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

include this subclass in your activity:

```
public class Typefaces{

        private final Hashtable<String, Typeface> cache = new Hashtable<String, Typeface>();

            public Typeface get(Context c, String name){
                synchronized(cache){
                    if(!cache.containsKey(name)){
                        Typeface t = Typeface.createFromAsset(
                                c.getAssets(), 
                                String.format("fonts/%s.ttf", name)
                            );
                        cache.put(name, t);
                    }
                    return cache.get(name);
                }
            }

        }
```

Then implement like this:

```
Typefaces tf = new Typefaces();

tvMessage.setTypeface(tf.get(context, "shruti"));
```

Don't forget to add .ttf files in to asset/fonts folder in your project.(create fonts folder if there is none.). and also fonts file name should be in small caps. in folder and in class as well.

Hope it Helps!!

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to switch at runtime 2 layouts. The best solution is to put 2 different LinearLayout inside the same layout and switch ( View.VISIBLE / View.GONE ) visibility of them when the users make their decision.